# Accessing 't' (from r18n) in a rack-unit test of a Sinatra app

Tags: unit-testing, internationalization, sinatra

When using `sinatra-r18n` to handle internationalisation, the `r18n` lib exposes a variable `t` for use within your helpers, routes and templates, as per [these instructions](https://github.com/ai/r18n/tree/master/sinatra-r18n).

I have written a simple unit test using `rack-unit` to confirm that some of my pluralisations work but the test throws an error claiming `t` is nil.

I've tried referencing it via `app.t`, `MySillyApp.t` (where MySillyApp is the name of my Sinatra app), `MySillyApp.settings.t` etc and none of them give me access to the `t` I need.

What I am trying to achieve is a confirmation that my translation files include all the keys I need corresponding to plurals of various metric units my app needs to understand. Perhaps there is a more direct way of testing this without going via the Sinatra app itself. I'd welcome any insight here.

Comment: More specific instructions might help. Your code, en.yml etc.

Comment: All I am trying to do is reference the translation files in my tests that my app has access to when it runs. I'm not doing anything special here or in any way out of the ordinary, so you really don't need examples of the code.  Any example of a unit test that references an i18n translation file will help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar task to check localized strings in my Cucumber scenarios.
I've made [working example](https://github.com/qatsi/sinatra-cucumber-r18n-example).
[Here](https://github.com/qatsi/sinatra-cucumber-r18n-example/blob/master/features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb) you can find how strings got translated.
[This file](https://github.com/qatsi/sinatra-cucumber-r18n-example/blob/master/features/support/env.rb) halps to understand how to add R18n support to your testing framework:

```
require 'r18n-core'
...

class SinCucR18nWorld
  ...
  include R18n::Helpers
end
```

As you can see instead of rack/unit I'm using RSpec/Cucumber, sorry.